# How can I insert the code Tag in YouTube website?

Tags: tags, ads

To use Google ADS for my campaign, the system as me to insert some lines of code (Tag) in my website, BUT the website is my Youtube channel, how can I insert the code into?
Or the TAG ADS is not for YouTube channel? I'd like to promote the YouTube channel (sorry for my English).
Thanks.